# https image url not working with picasso android

Tags: android

I am trying to download image from https url.

Using following code.

Url: https://bma8.officebrain.com/web/binary/image?model=res.partner&id=81936&field=image_medium&t=1425030983913

```
    Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://bma8.officebrain.com/web/binary/image?model=res.partner&id="+updateId+"&field=image_medium&t=1425030983913").into(new Target()
            {

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1)
                {

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    String encodedImageStr = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    meditModeImage = encodedImageStr;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0)
                {

                }
            });
```

above code not working https url.

replace with any http url working fine.

Please help me.

Comment: When I opened link I had page not found - maybe this is reason

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Url open in firefox browser.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Url open in firefox browser.

Comment: @Hemant: yes i'm opening in firefox

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Using the Picasso lib unable to get bitmap.

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak is there any way to download bitmap from url.

Comment: In my opinion the link is broken. You have to have right url to download image

Comment: @Hemant ?? I didn't ask you